# Non-trivial interior of Minkowski's sum of measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The question is:

> Let $$ A\subset\mathbb{R} $$ be a measurable set with positive Lebesgue's 
>   measure. Prove that $$ A - A $$ has non-empty interior.

I don't have idea how to even start proving this one. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Try writing down the indicator of $A-A$ using convolution, and the indicator of $A$.

Comment: @KesavKrishnan I think that this concept outreaches my knowledge and our curriculum at this moment. So I believe there should be some other way